# issue connecting to phpMyAdmin with Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've set up MySQL on my computer so that I can work with workbench. Next I installed XAMPP because I wanted to have a set up for working with PHP. I successfully was able to set up XAMPP and tested it with a index.php file which displays correctly (I did have some issues with ports, i had skype running on port 80 but now it's working). Now I'm trying to set up MySQL however when I try to do localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me a list of error:

[errorlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brEcT.png)

When I attempt to start MySQL in XAMPP control panel it shows me that an error that

```
2:38:10 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL1"!
2:38:10 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
2:38:10 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
2:38:10 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

THEN

```
I get an errro stating that MYSQL shutdown unexpectandly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependendies....
```

As it says above it shows that Port 3306 is in use but by mysqld.exe.....so why isn't this working? I check netstat and it is in fact in use by mysql .....Please be patient as this is my first time doing it.

I'm not sure if me setting up my MYSQL WorkBench has anything to do with it. I set up a password and username so that I can mess around with it, set up a db and some tables.

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Xampp will come with it's own version of MySQL, so if you have already installed MySQL on your machine separately, try changing the port that your Xampp MySQL uses to one that's not in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can only be installed once, also check if any other programs are using those ports.